# AWS Reverse Migration Set-Up localhost from AWS Console

Tags: python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam-cli

I have been building a web application using python and AWS console on a borrowed computer for the past month.
I recently obtained a new computer and I am trying to change from developing my app online in AWS console to offline on my localhost.
Online, I have already an existing API, lambda Fucntions, Api Gateway, DynamoDb Tables.
Offline,I have the following tools installed: Linux, Pycharm, python 3.9 AWS CLI 2, AWS SAM CLI, Docker.

My misunderstanding lies in how to replicate the organization of the directories on my local computer.
And is there a simple command to import or clone or set-up my entire app/api locally

Any advice, direction, documentation or tutorials related to this reverse migration issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: `rsync`, maybe?